# Laravel - Autenticação Website e API

Tags: laravel, api, autenticação, jwt

Estou desenvolvendo um Chat onde pode ser acessado tanto pela web quanto por uma aplicação, então fiz um projeto em laravel com uma api, tanto o site quanto a aplicação vão ser alimentados através da api que fica no mesmo servidor o que eu estou em dúvida é quanto a autenticação

**Aplicação**

Na minha aplicação eu estou usando *JWT* para autenticar o usuário, então a cada requisição eu preciso passar um *token*, esse token é obtido no momento do login

Depois irei guardar esse *token* em uma sessão local no dispositivo para não ter que ficar autenticando todo momento

**Web site**

Mas como devo fazer a autenticação no site, se eu já estou alimentando ele através da api eu deveria também fazer a autenticação através da api?

Logar, obter o *token*, guardar em uma sessão e em toda requisição passar o *token* obtido?

Me parece um método inseguro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se seu site é separado da sua aplicação, você pode, sem nenhum problema, requisitar os recursos da API pra alimentar o site. Agora, se ele estiver dentro do Laravel, você pode chamar os recursos da API internamente, ou acessar sua camada de serviço ou repositório, etc.

Um detalhe para esses casos de utilização de JWT é que ao autenticar no Aplicativo Mobile, e em seguida autenticar no site, você irá perder o Token.

Nesse caso, você irá precisar trabalhar com um SSO Server pra gerenciar essas sessões. Se for esse o caso, complemento a resposta, baseando-me no seu problema.

Comment: Sugestão: ou você passa as partes relevantes do link aqui pro site, para virar uma resposta mesmo,  ou posta como comentário (e avisa que o site é seu mesmo). Do jeito que tá, cai no que é classificado como Spam aqui. Note que não tem problema você complementar uma resposta com um link seu, desde que ela resolva de fato o post sem precisar do link, e o link complemente de fato. Mas nesse caso, sempre avisando quando o site é seu mesmo. Mais detalhes em [help]. Conhecendo o funcionamento do site, a comunidade vai aproveitar melhor sua boa vontade em ajudar e você será pontuado por isso.

Comment: A pergunta foi respondida e o site entrou como sugestão de uma possível necessidade, que não foi apresentada por quem fez a pergunta. Por isso, não trouxe o conteúdo do texto. Mas vou editar e remover o link, para não fazer o spam.

Comment: Pode deixar o link, mas ponha um aviso que é seu mesmo, fica mais legal. Se puder complementar a resposta, vai agregar valor e os votos podem ser revisados.